# How do I find out if my application is running on x86 or x64 Windows?

Tags: windows, version

I want to know, at run time, whether I'm running on 32 bit or 64 bit windows.  The OSVERSIONINFOEX structure tells me the major and minor version, but I'm guessing I need the build numbers.  Anyone know what they are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your application is compiled for 64-bit, then the answer's easy: you're running on 64-bit Windows.

If your application is compiled for 32-bit, you need to call [IsWow64Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684139.aspx). This function is only exported on Windows XP or later; if you want to support earlier versions of Windows, you'll need to use GetProcAddress to get a pointer to this function.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using C++, there's a very good OS detection class [here](http://www.naughter.com/dtwinver.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the build number already from the `OSVERSIONINFOEX` structure.

If you are a 32-bit process and want to know if you're running under WOW64 (ie., a 64-bit OS), call `IsWow64Process()`. (requires XP SP2 or later)

Answer (score 0):

I use WMI.

select * from Win32_OperatingSystem

Get the first instance, and then select the Version attribute. For WinXP, it returns 5.1.2600.