# How to know in run time if i'm on x86 or x64 mode in c#

Tags: c#, .net, x86, 64-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I tell if my application is running as a 32 or 64 bit application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266082/how-do-i-tell-if-my-application-is-running-as-a-32-or-64-bit-application)

Hi

I have an app in c# (Framework 3.5 SP1) and I need to load an unmanaged assembly at run time but there are two different versions, one for x86 and another for x64, so I need to know at run time in which mode is the app running

I have seen this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443227/how-do-i-find-out-if-my-application-is-running-on-x86-or-x64-windows) but it's for C++, is there an easier way to do it in C#? or how can I do this in C#?

Thanks

Comment: See: [c# - How to know a process is 32-bit or 64-bit programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953377/how-to-know-a-process-is-32-bit-or-64-bit-programmatically). If you upgrade to .NET 4.0, you can also use the [`Environment.Is64BitProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitprocess.aspx) property

Comment: @Ani: That's not a dupe, because it asks about detecting bitness of some *other* application.  But this is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266082/how-do-i-tell-if-my-application-is-running-as-a-32-or-64-bit-application

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I don't understand; that questions covers this too. The top answer on that question starts off by mentioning the `IntPtr.Size` technique.

Comment: @Ani: You're right that the answers to that question include answers to this one.

Comment: Fun fact: carefully-crafted x86 machine code can branch or not depending on whether it's being decoded as x86-64 or x86-32.  See [this polyglot machine-code Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38063529/x86-32-x86-64-polyglot-machine-code-fragment-that-detects-64bit-mode-at-run-ti).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can check whether [`IntPtr.Size`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.size.aspx) is `4` or `8`.

Comment: Correct, but I'm not going to reward you for answering an obvious dupe.

Comment: Just use: Environment.Is64BitProcess

Answer (score 14):

Use the `System.Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem` property, introduced in .NET 4.0. [According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitoperatingsystem.aspx):

Determines whether the current operating system is a 64-bit operating system, it returns `true` if the operating system is 64-bit; otherwise, `false`.

Comment: But it doesn't answer the question.  The main application could force loading in 32-bit mode even on a 64-bit OS if it needs other 32-bit only components.

Comment: That's new to .Net 4.0; he's using 3.5.

Comment: Check `IntPtr.Size == 8;`  if true, then the assembly is 64-bit, if the value is 4, then you are 32 bit.

Answer (score 8):

You can simply check the size of an `IntPtr` via `IntPtr.Size` to see what your process is running as:

- If it is 8 bytes, then you are running as an x64 process.
- If it is 4 bytes, then you are running as an x86 process..

In .NET you can set your `Platform Target` in your project properties to `Any CPU` to automatically run your application as x64 on an x64 OS and x86 on an x86 OS with the same binary.

---

Your application could run in x86 even on an x64 OS since a process that starts it could be running on WOW64 emulation and it starts your process.  Here are some additional ways to [run your x64 process as an x86 process](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/gabrielschenker/archive/2009/10/21/force-net-application-to-run-in-32bit-process-on-64bit-os.aspx) on an x64 OS.

Comment: Although your explanation is wrong (it doesn't tell you the architecture you're on), this will work.  Note that changing the CPU property when building a C# DLL will just cause crashes if there's a mismatch, it won't control the bitness.  The main application could be loading in 32-bit mode even on a 64-bit OS if it needs other 32-bit only components.

Comment: Replaced the word architecture with "as an x__ process" and fixed to explain about wow64 emulation a bit, thx.

Answer (score -4):

This MSDN blog post is a good start. `GetEnvironmentVariable("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE").ToString()` also see the `GetPlatform` code in [Mono Paint](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid495E7D0ED07BA35F5F0CE0EEFE87D7375BF1CF55.aspx).

Comment: This tells you if the underlying platform is 64-bit capable, not whether your program is running in 64-bit mode.

Comment: It is not save to rely upon environment variables, PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE can be changed or be other than expected in the future OS'es