# "undefined symbol rax, rbx, rcx, rdx" in MASM Visual Studio

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, cpu-registers

Following is the code:

```
.386

.model flat, stdcall

.stack 4096

    ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode:DWORD

    .DATA

    .code

Main proc

mov rax,0

mov rbx,0

mov rcx,0

mov rdx,0

       mov al, 0F0H           ;using 8-bit register

    mov bx, 1012H            ;using 16-bit register

    mov ecx, 15284H          ;using 32-bit register
   
    mov rdx, 3578815H        ;using 64-bit register


INVOKE ExitProcess, 0

main ENDP

END main
```

Whenever I run this, it says:

> undefined symbol rax, rbx, rcx, rdx

But it works when I use:

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096
    ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode:DWORD
    .DATA
    .code
Main proc

mov eax,0

mov ebx,0

mov ecx,0

mov edx,0

       mov al, 0F0H           ;using 8-bit register

    mov bx, 1012H            ;using 16-bit register

    mov ecx, 15284H          ;using 32-bit register  
 
    mov edx, 3578815H        ;using 64-bit register  

INVOKE ExitProcess, 0

main ENDP

END main
```

I'm using x86 configuration. x64 doesn't work for me. Could someone tell me why RAX, RBX, RCX, and RDX aren't working?

Comment: 80386 CPU has no 64-bit general purpose registers.

Comment: Do you know how i can access 64 bit registers then?

Comment: there are no 64 bit (general purpose) registers to access.

Comment: So youre saying I can't see how 64 bit registers are working and it's only limited to 32- bit registers or lower? Is there surely no other way to see how 64 bit registers are working?

Comment: @TheChannel Specifying `.386` directive you limited assembler by 80386 capabilities. To use 64 bit registers you have to specify target which has ones. I guess MASM has directives or command line options for x86_64. Sorry, i'm not familiar with modern MASM.

Answer (score 2):

For Visual Studio, a 64 bit build would use ML64.EXE instead of MASM.EXE. Don't use .386 directive. There is no .model directive for ML64.EXE, since the 64 bit calling convention is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

**You can't use 64-bit registers in 32-bit code.**

In 16-bit mode, 32-bit registers are usable in machine code with `66h` and `67h` prefixes.  So 16 and 32-bit code can both use instructions like `movzx ax, byte ptr [ecx]` (assuming the code is running on a 386 or newer, of course, hence `.model 386` telling the assembler that it should let you write code like that).

But for x86-64, there wasn't an unused byte left for use as a prefix in 32-bit mode, so the AMD64 architects had to do it differently.  The new features of x86-64 are *only* available in 64-bit mode, not in 32-bit compat mode.

The actual mechanism they picked was to remove the 1-byte encodings for `inc reg` and `dec reg`, and reuse those `0x4?` bytes as REX prefixes, including a Width bit to distinguish `add eax, ecx` from `add rax, rcx`, and 3 extra bits for register numbers, allowing access to r8-r15 for instructions like `add r8d, [r9 + r10]`.

---

As https://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#REX_prefix says,
**The REX prefix is only available in long mode.**

Fun fact:  If you try to execute 64-bit machine code with the CPU in 32-bit mode (e.g. from using NASM `bits 64` in the source and assembling with `nasm -fwin32`), the REX prefixes will decode as `inc` or `dec` instructions.

You can play fun tricks like making machine code that runs 3 different ways depending on what mode it executes in. For example,  *[x86-32 / x86-64 polyglot machine-code fragment that detects 64bit mode at run-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38063529/x86-32-x86-64-polyglot-machine-code-fragment-that-detects-64bit-mode-at-run-ti)*.  Also a [3-way codegolf answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/139243/determine-your-languages-version/139717#139717) shows disassembly of the same code 3 different ways.

Comment: Tysm! Youre awesome!